# How to UTF-8 encode and replace text inside txt file?

Tags: python, replace, utf-8

I am trying to write an application that opens the txt files inside selected (sub)folder(s) and replace all the letters "ž" with letters "š" and save it in `UTF-8` format.

This is what i managed to do so far (**VERSION 2 - see edit**):

```
import os
import codecs

startIn = os.getcwd()

print()
print("Pregledujem: " + startIn + "\\")
print("-------------------------")

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(startIn):
  print()
  print("Trenutna mapa: " + dirName + "\\")
  for fname in fileList:
    if fname.endswith(".srt"):
      fullpath = dirName + "\\" + fname
      print("  Podnapis: " + fname )
      with codecs.open(fullpath, 'r+', "UTF-8-sig") as cursub:
        lines = cursub.read().replace("ž","š")
        cursub.seek(0)
        cursub.write(lines)
```

**EDIT**

Replacing the letters now works like it should, but I still cant figure out how to properly encode file TO `utf-8`.

Current version outputs the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9a in position
>   220: invalid start byte

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: You are replacing but you are not writing it back; when you do `line.replace` it doesn't write the line back, it just modifies it. The other problem you have is you opened the file for writing, which will delete its contents; which means that `line` won't contain the letters you want to replace.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read and write open in `r+` mode

```
cursub = codecs.open(filename, 'r+',"utf-8")
lines = cursub.read().replace("š", "ž")
cursub.seek(0)  # go back to start of file
cursub.write(lines) # rewrite updated lines
```

Using with will close the file automatically:

```
with codecs.open(filename, 'r+',"utf-8") as cursub: 
    lines = cursub.read().replace("š", "ž")
    cursub.seek(0)
    cursub.write(lines)
```

Comment: Great, replacing works like it should now :) except the encoding stays the ASCII instead of UTF-8. Any suggestions?

PS Whats with all the negative votes people?

Answer (score 0):

if you are ging to edit (or rather rewrite) a file you shouldn't open it in write mode because that makes it impossible to read from it.
Either read the full file into memory first or write to a copy while reading from the original (or make a copy first and read from the copy, rewriting the original).